# System Settings doesn't close and continuously changes focus to itself from any other window

Tags: system-settings, 16.04, unity-control-center

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 from 14.04.

When I run **System Settings**, my CPU usage goes to 100%, and the Settings window always remains in focus. I tried to open System Monitor to kill System Settings, but the focus kept on changing back to Settings. When I click the close button, the current instance of Settings closes, but at the same time a new instance of the window pops up.

The only solution I found was to log out of the system.

Output of `apt-cache policy unity-control-center`:

```
unity-control-center:
  Installed: 15.04.0+16.04.20160413-0ubuntu3
  Candidate: 15.04.0+16.04.20160413-0ubuntu3
  Version table:
 *** 15.04.0+16.04.20160413-0ubuntu3 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     15.04.0+16.04.20160413-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://jp.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Exact same problem here. `xkill` does not help either, another instance respawns instantly.

Comment: I noticed this only happens after launching the Settings dialog and clicking on either "Text Entry" or "Details". Same for you?

Comment: Is this the same issue: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/activity-log-manager/+bug/1274728

Comment: When started from command line it appears that some libraries are missing: `libgnome-desktop-3.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory`. Which is turn is due to dependencies bugs that hit me when upgrading from 2015.10 to 2016.04: `ifupdown : Breaks: systemd (< 228-3~)`

Comment: @saji89: It indeed sounds similar (apart from that page being for 14.04 and mentioning a released fix)

Comment: @Sneetsher: Reproduced with both my usual account and Ubuntu's automatic guest account. I took the liberty to add `apt-cache policy unity-control-center` to the body of the question since it is too big for a comment and there is no sign of life from acceptedfreak.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, another output for `apt-cache policy systemd libgnome-desktop-3-12` and what do you get when trying to fix missing dependency with `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: @Sneetsher: Actually I ran `apt-get install -f` just yesterday. Maybe that fixes the problem, actually?

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, that is expected to fix  the problem of the missing lib `libgnome-desktop-3.so.12` , by updating systemd (< 228-3~). the current one is v229 then installed libgnome-desktop-3-12. You can check the history using `zmore /var/log/dpkg.log* | grep -e " purge " -e " remove " -e "install " | sort > ~/Desktop/dpkg-histroy-$(date -I).txt` and see what installed or removed yesterday, If you can share that portion through http://paste.ubuntu.com .I will be thankful, I'm curios to know what happen too.

Comment: @Sneetsher: Here is the result: https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/bab5d3919eecf652b1b85b4a7d94b9d4 (I removed the lines timestamped before I upgraded to 2016.04)

Comment: @Sneetsher: Unfortunately dpkg.log does not go back to yesterday: https://gist.github.com/nicolas-raoul/1d1966217eec9f1afb02389292de930c

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, you may find old logs under same folder `dpkg.log.1` or `dpkg.log.1.gz` ...

Comment: I prepended with the content of dpkg.log.1 thanks!

Comment: Try [Ubuntu falls back to old window style on every second boot](http://askubuntu.com/questions/789456/ubuntu-falls-back-to-old-window-style-on-every-second-boot) and post the outcome.

Comment: @NicolasRaoul, I tried reproducing same issue by downgrading to systemd-sysv 225 and libgnome-desktop-3-10.  systemd-sysv seems not related. libgnome-desktop-3-10, I couldn't even login (login loop). God knows! Whatever, the important thing you get yours resolved.

Comment: Are you operating on a completely clean install? Or do you have non-stock applications installed?

I know I install a variety of additional options in Settings, and modify or create files like Xmodmap that affect the settings of various applications. I have seen this crash Settings before.

Answer (score 1):

This was a [bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/activity-log-manager/+bug/1274728) that has since been patched. The version of `unity-control-center` shown in your output from `apt-cache policy unity-control-center` is out of date.

I issued the following commands:

`sudo apt-get purge unity-control-center`

`sudo apt-get install unity-control-center`

`sudo apt-get install unity-control-center-signon`

Note the change in output.

```
$ apt-cache policy unity-control-center
unity-control-center:
 Installed: 15.04.0+16.04.20170214-0ubuntu2
  Candidate: 15.04.0+16.04.20170214-0ubuntu2
```